# How can the Unsullied form a new House?

Tags: plot-explanation, game-of-thrones

In the finale of *Game of Thrones*, Sir Davos suggests Grey Worm  to go somewhere with beautiful lands and start their own house.

but:

1. The Unsullied are all men
2. The Unsullied are all eunuchs!

The most probable plot is to go there and stay as long as they live and then extinct! How are they gonna start their own house?

Comment: They could start their own military company/order. But they went to Naanth and probably gonna die within a year now.

Comment: And that's not a "house". Also unsullied are not like Dothraki, they're an army! They're not "people"

Comment: @user28434 an army for what? They all live happily ever after now.

Comment: @JJJ, `happily ever after` doesn't ever happen. Their world will keep going, wars will keep going, wars will keep needing armies. P.S. Only thing that could stop all the wars by uniting everyone in the Hive Mind was killed midseason.

Answer (score 2):

I don't get the impression they intend to start a noble house, just that they are going to continue Dany's original mission of protecting the unprotected.

Also, Grey Worm wants to honor his pledge to Missandei, and the Unsullied have nothing better to do.

Comment: What about seeking the justice for their dead queen and grey worm's beloved one who died for his queen?

Comment: @nitwit Cersei is dead (re: Missandei) and Grey Worm did want Jon executed. Tyrion states to Jon that Grey Worm accepted the life sentence of the Night's Watch.